# License error to Execute razl exe from Sitecore powershell script

Tags: powershell, automation, razl

I am trying to automate content migration to upper environment using razl and Sitecore PowerShell.
While executing razl exe through Sitecore powershell module, getting license error.
**error: you do not have active license for razl**

I do have razl license and able to execute the same script from windows powershell.

```
& exe path/razl.exe "/script:xml file path"
```

I will like to utilize sitecore powershell script with scheduled task. Any suggestion to resolve this issue.

Comment: Please see our Sitecore Razl PowerShell Connections documentation for this use case: http://hedgehogdevelopment.github.io/razl/script.html#running-scripts-in-build-pipelines